# Passing each element of a List to a function in Scala

Tags: scala, function

Issue: I am trying to pass each element of list to a function in Scala

Need to pass elements of myList to arg y in the add function, here x has a constant value which is 5

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
val myList = List(2,3,4)
```

Expected Output:
7
8
9

Comment: `myList.map(add(5,_))`

Comment: @Tim I understand that this looks like a very trivial question, but consider that OP could be a complete beginner and lack the experience to effectively look up by himself. I would recommend suggesting places to have a look at, like this tutorial for beginners on the standard library: https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/standard_library

Comment: @stefanobaghino This is not the place for beginners to learn Scala, nor is it the place to ask for recommendations (there is even a close option for that one). And googling the question gives plenty of links that will explain the basics like this.

Comment: OP did not ask for recommendations. On the other hand, providing recommendations in comments to trivial question can gently kickstart one's ability to do the research on their own. If you believe this question does not belong to StackOverflow, vote to close, it's a legitimate tool to use if this is not something that brings value to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to apply the function `add` to each element in `myList` which returns a new `List`.

```
scala> val x = 5
val x: Int = 5

scala> myList.map(myListElement => add(x,myListElement))
val res19: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: More idiomatically written as `myList.map(add(x, _))`.

Comment: Or: `val add5 = add(5, _); myList.map(add5)`

Comment: Or even `myList.map(_ + 5)`

Comment: Those are perfectly good approaches that I'm aware of but was trying to provide the simplest and clearest approach based on OP being new with likely little Scala background.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive way of doing it:

```
def sum(x: Int = 5, y: Int): Int = x + y

def sumElem(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def sumElemAcc(xs: List[Int], sumXS: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) sumXS
    else sumElemAcc(xs.tail, sumXS :+ sum(y = xs.head))
  }
  sumElemAcc(xs, List())
}

val myList = List(2,3,4)

sumElem(myList)
```

Output:

```
res0: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers work fine but if you want to do things in more functional style and different approach consider trying following:

```
def add(x:Int,y:Int):Int = x+y
val add_5 = (y:Int) => add(5,y)
val li = List(1,2,3)
li.map(add_5) // for me mapping function like this is more intuitive i.e. without arguments
```

If you want to try curried and partially applied ways. Consider trying one of the followings also:

```
//example of eta expansion is x=> f(x)
  val simpleAddFun = (x:Int, y:Int) => x+y  //this is a fn that will be eta expanded
  def simpleAddMethod(x:Int, y:Int) = x+y //this is method
  def curriedAddMethod(x:Int)(y:Int) = x+y //this is curried method

  //Implement add7
  val add_7 = (y:Int) => simpleAddFun(7,y)
  //or simply
  val add_7_2 = simpleAddFun.curried(7)

  //or we can tell compiler to do eta expansion.... by _ at last of curried method
  val add_7_eta = curriedAddMethod(7)_  //we can say it partially applied fn
  val add_7_eta2 = curriedAddMethod(7)(_) //alternative syntax also works for non curried fns/methods

  //using simple methods/fns like curried..
  val add_7_sim = simpleAddFun(7, _:Int)
  val add_7_sim2 = simpleAddMethod(7, _:Int)
```

Although currying and partially applied functions are rarely used in writing real world apps and things can also be done without them. But sometimes knowing them makes your code look more clean and matured. Consider using official doc for more clarity.